# WSDL Type for getter without parameter

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, xsd

I try to write a wsdl file. And I start with defining in the  element my future operations.
So I need to define a method like getAllObjects. That's why I don't need to set any parameter to getAllObjectsRequest. 
Could anybody tell me how I must define my message and operations for a method which doesn't declare any inputparameters (like ID in getById).

At the moment I have the next code:

```
<type .....>
<xsd:element name="getAllObjectRequest">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

        <xsd:element name="getAllObjectResponce">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="allObject" type="wsbean:ObjectADB"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
```

I think this is not corect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This syntax is correct. If you don't like it, I suggest creating special marker `Void` type for these kind of messages:

```
<xsd:element name="getAllObjectRequest" type="Void"/>

<xsd:complexType name="Void">
    <xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Note that valid request in SOAP message look like this:

```
<getAllObjectRequest/>
```

Comment: jaxb seems also to bind this to void +1