# WSDL generate method with no parameters

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I try to generate webservice using WSDL file. There is one method with no input parameter. I did it the following way:

```
...
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://api.registration.company.com"
    xmlns:base="http://base.api.registration.company.com">
    ...
    <xsd:element name="RemoveURLRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="RemoveURLResponse" type="xsd:boolean" />
</xsd:schema>
</types>
...
<message name="RemoveURLRequest">
    <part name="RemoveURLRequest" element="tns:RemoveURLRequest" />
</message>
<message name="RemoveURLResponse">
    <part name="RemoveURLResponse" element="tns:RemoveURLResponse" />
</message>
...
<portType name="RegistrationService">
    ...
    <operation name="RemoveURL">
        <input message="tns:RemoveURLRequest" />
        <output message="tns:RemoveURLResponse" />
    </operation>
...
</portType>
<binding name="RegistrationServiceSOAP" type="tns:RegistrationService">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    ...
    <operation name="RemoveURL">
        <soap:operation soapAction=
            "http://api.registration.company.com/web/services/RegistrationService/RemoveURL"
                style="document" />
            <input>
                <soap:body parts="RemoveURLRequest" use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body parts="RemoveURLResponse" use="literal" />
            </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="RegistrationService">
    <port name="RegistrationServiceSOAP" binding="tns:RegistrationServiceSOAP">
        <soap:address location=
            "http://api.registration.company.com/web/services/RegistrationService" />
    </port>
</service>
```

According to this WSDL I expect method to be generated like this:

```
public boolean removeURL();
```

But I'm getting this:

```
public boolean removeURL(RemoveURLRequest removeURLRequest);
```

Where RemoveURLRequest is an empty class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "RemoveURLRequest")
public class RemoveURLRequest {

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems what you want is not possible, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134348/wsdl-type-for-getter-without-parameter

Answer (score 2):

try some thing like this

<message name="RemoveURLRequest">

</message>

without using the part element.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried this already but it gives me the following error: `[ERROR] parts "RemoveURLRequest" not found in the message "RemoveURLRequest", wrong WSDL` :(

Answer (score 1):

You must create an empty complex Type and use it as parameter. see the following post which is a similar question : [WSDL Type for getter without parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134348/wsdl-type-for-getter-without-parameter?lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Jax-WS usually generate such code when the message/part/schema types ends with the keyword "Request". Give it a try without by removing the "Request" part of the name. This should give you the expected results

Comment: Thank you for reply @gastush Tried this but it did not solve the problem. I removed all the request keywords from the types names, but still get the same result. :(